# Set background color on splashscreen and tiles for Windows Store Applications

Tags: windows-store-apps

I don't want to use the default grey backgruond color for my Splashscreen and Tile backgrounds. Where can I change this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realize that this is done in the menu Project / Store / Edit App Manifest, and set the "Background color".

Answer (score 6):

Opening the "package.appxmanifest" file in your Solution Explorer will get you there as well :)